# Создание переменных на странице

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Как на странице chhtml в mvc проекте объявить переменную?
Я попробовал `@int i = 0;` но так не работает. Выдаёт ошибку.

> CS1525    Invalid expression term 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так - со скобками:

```
@{int i = 0;}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Раздел с заголовком "Razor code blocks".

Comment: Igor а в чём разница между @() и @{} и просто @. Не могу понять что то. Или подскажите где про это можно почитать?